# Custom Tab Bar Icons not presenting at correct size?

Tags: swift, xcode, icons, tabbar

I have created my own custom tab bar icons. I have saved them at sizes:

```
22pt x 22pt with file name iconname@1x.png
44pt x 44pt with file name iconname@2x.png
66pt x 66pt with file name iconname@3x.png
```

After importing these files into the asset folder I've used the code:

[image]

```swift
let homeController = HomeViewController()
        homeController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "home"), tag: 1)
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
```

The icon is presented but at a very large size. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was saving it at 300 resolution so the image was larger than I thought.